# EAP 6 datasource fault tolerant configuration load balancing between two SQL servers?

Tags: sql-server, configuration, jboss, datasource, jboss6.x

Environment: Jboss EAP 6.4
I have the following datasource configuration in my standalone-ha.xml

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/localPrimaryDS" pool-name="IntegrationDS1" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" statistics-enabled="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://primarySqlServer;databaseName=HalfFat|jdbc:sqlserver://secondarySqlServer;databaseName=HalfFat</connection-url>
    <driver>mssql</driver>
    <url-delimiter>|</url-delimiter>
    <pool>
        <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
        <prefill>true</prefill>
        <use-strict-min>true</use-strict-min>
        <flush-strategy>IdleConnections</flush-strategy>
    </pool>
    <security>
        <user-name>user</user-name>
        <password>psswd</password>
    </security> 
    <validation>                    
        <validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>
        <background-validation>false</background-validation>
        <background-validation-millis>60000</background-validation-millis>
        <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mssql.MSSQLValidConnectionChecker"></valid-connection-checker>
        <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mssql.MSSQLExceptionSorter"></exception-sorter>
    </validation>
</datasource>
```

Observation:
When both SQL servers are present, the application exclusively obtained the JDBC connections from the primary sql server instance. When I paused/disabled the primary sql server, on the application level I observed that the broken connections are destroyed/new connections are obtained from secondary sql server instance. All as expected. However, I observed the mix of two connections if I resumed/re-enabled the primary sql server instance.

Question:
This is somehow an undesired behavior as I expect that application to keep using the connections from secondary database until it fails. Is there something I can configure on the datasource to disable this "load balancing" behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that `<use-strict-min>true</use-strict-min>`is what is causing the issue. According to [redhat](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/457243), When use-strict-min is set to true, the idle connection scan will not mark for closure any further connections once the min-pool-size (in-use + available connections) has been reached. As a result, I assume, there are still some connections from the primary database that were not marked for closure and unpausing the SQL server would make those uncleaned connections available again.